# Nexus 7 says it's charging but it isn't

Tags: charging, nexus-7

I have had a Nexus 7 since September and today something strange happened.

I plugged it in, as usual, to recharge the battery. It charged up to 36% and now it still says it's charging but it never moves from that percentage.

How can I fix my device?

Comment: Could try turning it off and on again? Charging whilst off? Charging via PC using USB?

Comment: I was originally charging it via USB. Then I tried to use the wall plug. I still have to try with the device powered off.

Comment: If that doesn't work out, it might help to remove the battery for a few minutes, then put it back in.

Comment: It doesn't work. How can I remove the battery from a nexus 7?

Comment: You can't remove the battery that easy. I guess there is some app that's consuming too much power, and with normal usb charging it pulls only 500 mA. Reboot the device and try again.

Comment: What is the right way to reboot? I try to hold the power button and then press power off, but it seems just to hibernate rather than reboot

Comment: When you press `power off` and it hibernates, it goes to a deep sleep. You can still wake it up by a long press on the power button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue using a 2A charger instead of my phone 1A charger or the USB port that provides only 0.5A.

I am sure I have been able to charge my nexus with all the power sources, but maybe I left it on charge all night long.

Comment: As you have found, a bigger charger helps.  Also check to see what is running.  One graphics intensive game I play tends to consume 25% of the battery / hour when I have everything turned up.  Even the stock charger barely keeps up with it.

Comment: I wasn't paying. I was just surfing the web, reading the news and interacting on social networks

Answer (score 0):

Actually Nexus 7 battery is easy to change. The back is easily carefully pried off, the connector inside comes undone without much effort. I replaced my battery with a new one still it only recharges to about 50% then begins to discharge. I'm going to try a slightly stronger charger. Though even fully powered off and charging over night did not increase charge though the indicator claims it is charging.

Comment: I don't think it addresses "*How can I fix my device?*"

Answer (score -2):

Try calibrating (Completely Discharge battery), by playing games or watching videos. Once battery dries try switching your nexus on untill your device refuses to do so. The charge it from a wall charger. See if it works. I have a motorola MB855 , i generally claibrate 5-10 times in a month. That keeps its backup and life healthy.

Comment: "Calibrating" a Li-ion battery the way you do will cause the battery life to be reduced drastically. Don't do this.

Comment: I hav'nt faced any single problems past 6 years, either with laptop or mobile phones. I am using mobiles since 11 years when we have NiCd batteries, claibrating batteries will help you in taking full advantage of your battery.

Comment: Well, if you want to go against everything the mobile manufacturers say, more power to you! Enjoy your amazing battery life!

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi : Kid ... Read this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490. Calibration is Highly Recommended by HP and Apple for their devices. Even HP laptop box comes with instruction to calibrate battery on regular intervals. And these days Mobile and Laptop batteries are both Li-On battery. Only sizes and mAH are different. If calibrating is considered as bad idea , then the laptop or tab manufacturer will suggest you to operate the device while charging. Instead they suggest to use it on battery as max as possible. Over charging or online usage is always said to be avoided

Comment: @See-Sharp The Apple article you post says "every few months", not "5-10 times in a month" or maybe once per month if you leave it plugged in constantly (not the case on a phone or tablet). Each time you do it puts wear and tear on the battery. You're doing it way more often than needed to keep the charge monitoring working.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using a 7" Galaxy Tab (SHW-180S) and this same thing happened with me a few days ago. This is how I solved it:

1. Remove the battery from the device
2. Charge your battery from another electric source (I don't remember the device name but most mobile repair shops have them)

You can also try a hard reset. Changing your charger may also help if it isn't providing enough power to charge Nexus 7.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to remove the battery from a Nexus 7

Comment: Would you please describe the reason of the down vote?